# Bootstrap modal won't focus no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button which pops up a modal, it does pop up & is functional. The form is in there how it should be, etc. Just one thing doesn't work which is that the modal just isn't focusing. I also tried doing it with JS which I found on another stackoverflow post but that didn't help me either.

The code

```html
<div class="modal" id="joinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="joinModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="joinModal">Inschrijven voor de Austronauten opleiding</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="../action/handler.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fullName">Je volledige naam</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Henk Smit" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Je email adres</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="naam@email.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="age">Wat is je leeftijd?</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="0"
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="degree">Van welk niveau kom je?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="degree" name="degree">
                            <option>Mavo</option>
                            <option>Havo</option>
                            <option>VWO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Inschrijven</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Shows up an unfocussed modal when it's called.

The button that triggers the modal

````html
<button type="button" class="btn text-success bg-transparent" style="box-shadow: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" autofocus>Inschrijven</button>```
````

Comment: What exactly do you want to focus, the whole modal popup or something inside the modal?

Comment: Whole modal popup

Comment: To do that you need to give the element an attribute `tabindex="0"` and then with JS `document.querySelector("#joinModal").focus()` - however this leaves me wondering: why do you want the modal to be focused by the user? It would make more sense if you focused on an input inside the modal - focusing the whole modal appears odd to me and make affect the accessibility of your modal! Food for thought anyway 

Comment: -> I can see you already have a tabindex attribute - it may also be worth adding some styling so you can verify the modal is focusing correctly. Something like (CSS): `<style>#joinModal:focus {outline: 2px solid blue;}</style>`

Comment: It's still not focussing nor adding an outline

Comment: Hmm, is it possible for you to move your testing code into JSFiddle and post a link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/820bwcdk/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `shown.bs.modal` event. More about this in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#how-it-works).

So when that event fires for your modal, just target the first `input` and focus it.

There is no use in focussing a `div`. A focussed `input` generally is what a user wants.

```js
$("#joinModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
  $(this).find("input").first().focus()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button type="button"  class="btn text-success bg-transparent" style="box-shadow: none;" data-toggle="modal" onclick="focus()" data-target="#joinModal" autofocus>Inschrijven
</button>

<div class="modal" id="joinModal" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="joinModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="joinModal">Inschrijven voor de Austronauten opleiding</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="../action/handler.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fullName">Je volledige naam</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Henk Smit"
                               autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Je email adres</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="naam@email.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="age">Wat is je leeftijd?</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="0"
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="degree">Van welk niveau kom je?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="degree" name="degree">
                            <option>Mavo</option>
                            <option>Havo</option>
                            <option>VWO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Inschrijven</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it with javascript (without jquery)

```
//optional: if you want to open the modal from a javascript function
const modalCrear = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance('#joinModal');
modalCrear.show();

//selecting the modal
const modalElement = document.getElementById('joinModal');

modalElement.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  //selecting the first input field
  const fullNameInput = document.getElementById('fullName');
  //adding the focus
  fullNameInput.focus();
});
```